# Pyinstaller : .exe file doesn't work the same way as in IDE

Tags: python, pyinstaller, eel, asammdf

I have written a python script, using `eel` for the GUI, that converts & does some calculations on files in a folder. **For this, i am using a python library called `asammdf`**. The code works well in an IDE but when i use `pyinstaller`and create a `.exe` file the code doesn't seem to work the same way.

```
import eel
from pathlib import Path
from asammdf import MDF
from pathlib import Path
import glob
import sys
import os
from datetime import timedelta


eel.init("path\to\folder\Python")
def python_code():
    # a python script that uses asammdf

@eel.expose
```

I have tried copying the `asammdf` directory into the python folder and `pyinstaller` seems to include it in the `.exe` dist folder but still it doesn't work. Can anyone help me out please?

**The error message comes as --**

```
asammdf\mdf.py:4597: UserWarning: The argument `ignore_invalid_signals` from the method `extract_bus_logging` is no longer used and will be removed in the future
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eel\__init__.py", line 281, in _process_message
  File "converterrxd_csv.py", line 79, in pythoncode
  File "asammdf\mdf.py", line 4625, in extract_bus_logging
  File "asammdf\mdf.py", line 4666, in _extract_can_logging
  File "asammdf\blocks\utils.py", line 1807, in load_can_database
  File "canmatrix\formats\__init__.py", line 71, in loadp
  File "canmatrix\formats\__init__.py", line 86, in load
KeyError: 'canmatrix.formats.dbc'
```

I tried installing the can-matrix package as well but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: What are you typing in the terminal when you use pyinstaler - i.e., are you using onefile? Do you have all the correct hook files in the pyinstaler folder - e.g., `hook-asammdf.py`? Are you getting any errors or warnings when running pyinstaller?

Comment: i typed this `pyinstaller <filename>.py --hidden-import asammdf` . No the installation & .exe creation did not give any error. @It_is_Chris

Comment: Go into the pyinstaller hook folder and make sure all the packages you are using have a hook file. If not, you will probably need to create a hook file for the ones missing.

Comment: @it_is_Chris I did use hooks to import the `asammdf` library but the error still persists. The Key error is shown as  `canmatrix.formats.dbc` but i havent used that in my code. I tried putting that in the hooks file but still the error message doesn't change. Do you know what could be the issue?

Comment: I found a solution. That is to manually copy the can-matrix folder to the dist folder after the '.exe' file is made. 'Pyinstaller' is somehow not including the complete can-matrix package to the dist folder. This works for now, but what if i want to create a single '.exe' file? In that case, manually copying the packages would not work. What are your thoughts?

Comment: using onefile is they way to go so try doing `pyinstaller some_pyhon_file.py -F`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the hidden import for canmatrix

see https://github.com/danielhrisca/asammdf/blob/180a1588737ae7aaf367aaa8fd1c81aff616df16/asammdf.spec#L37